# Subqueries in LinqToSql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have several tables (condensed down to:)

```
Bookings
+--------+------+------------+
| BKName | BkId | BkActivity |
+--------+------+------------+
Functions
+-------+--------+------+-----+-------+---------+---------+
| FName | FStart | FEnd | FID | FBkId | FRmCode | FEvents |
+-------+--------+------+-----+-------+---------+---------+
Rooms
+--------+--------+
| RmName | RmCode |
+--------+--------+
F2
+----------+------+
| UniqueId | Item |
+----------+------+
B2
+----------+------+
| UniqueId | Item |
+----------+------+
```

In SQL my query is

```
Select b.BkName
       r.RmName
       f.FName
       f.FStart
       f.FEnd
       f.FID
From Bookings as b
    Inner Join Functions as f
        on b.BkId = f.BkId
    Left Outer Join Rooms as r
        on f.FRmCode = r.RmCode
Where (b.BkActivity <> 'C') and (f.FEvents = 1)
and isnull((Select Item
            from F2
            where UniqueId = F.FID),0)=0
and isnull((Select Item
            from B2
            where UniqueId = b.BkId),0)=0
```

I'm trying to use Enity Framework and by extension LINQtoSQL but am having a devil of a time getting the same info back. I believe my issue is the two sub-queries messing things up and the Left Outer Join. All variations I've tried end up returning nothing.

Comment: Worth posting your current attempt with Entity Framework (even though it does not work as expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
var bookings = GetBookings();
var functions = GetFunctions();
var rooms = GetRooms();
var f2 = GetF2();
var b2 = GetB2();
var result = from booking in bookings
                     join function in functions on booking.Id equals function.FBkId
                     join room in rooms on function.FRmCode equals room.Code into bfr
                     from entry in bfr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where booking.Activity != "C" && function.FEvents == 1
                     && (from i in f2 where i.UniqueId == function.FId select i.Item).FirstOrDefault() == 0
                     && (from i in b2 where i.UniqueId == booking.Id select i.Item).FirstOrDefault() == 0
                     select new
                     {
                         BookingName = booking.Name,
                         RoomName = entry.Name,
                         FunctionName = function.Name,
                         Start = function.Start,
                         End = function.End,
                         FId = function.FId
                     };
```

It would be helpful to know the types of your columns. I'd also try to optimize the queries in the `where` clause, but that would require more knowledge of your DB. Keep in mind this code may not be as performant as an SQL stored procedure. If performance matters to you, I'd advise you to log the SQL output and measure the time it takes to execute the select.

Comment: This didn't exactly work for me, but it put me on the right direction. For reasons I can't explain I had to make two seperate sub queries outside of the main to join f2 to functions and b2 to bookings and then use those where you've got the subqueries in the where statement. I believe it's because I'm using a DefaultIfEmpty on them. I'll still accept this due to it putting me on the right track with little modification.